# Creating lead sheets using MuseScore

Tags: sheet-music, software, musescore, lead-sheets

I'm trying to separate a choral arrangement into simplified individual sheets for the different parts and instruments.

Need to be able to create a sheet with:

1. Music
2. Lyrics
3. Chords

I have issues adding lyrics. When I press <kbd>Cmd+K</kbd> to enter chords, the measure gets adjusted to make sure the chords fit. However the same is not true when I press <kbd>Cmd+L</kbd> for lyrics. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this tutorial. Part 1: https://musescore.org/node/11723. Part 2: https://musescore.org/en/node/11726

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? The notes don't move around at all when you type the lyrics in? Perhaps you can post an image of how it looks wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Musescore should automatically adjust the positions of notes to fit the lyrics. If it is not, then you may have a setting somewhere that is locking down the positions of the notes and preventing them from moving automatically.

Also be aware that if you see a little angled arrow symbol at the end of a line, that means Musescore won't move a measure to the next line if it gets crowded. You'll have to either move it yourself or remove the fixed newline.

See the following image for an example:
[image]

Comment: I had an angled arrow at the end of the line. Let me check if removing that fixes the problem.

Comment: Is this a Todd Wilcox original? 'Cause it's stuck in my head now...

Comment: "Well, i never imagined, back when I got my start on Music.SE, that I'd end up here receiving a Grammy from all you wonderful people. I do have to give thanks to someone who always believed in me, even when I didn't believe in myself: @GeneralNuisance"